# How to subdivide a textfile into several separate arrays with numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, analysis

I have a text file that I would like to subdivide into 3 separate text files based on the value in one of the rows. If LineID is 1 I want to move all rows with that LineID to a separate array or even a separate text file.

Text file output:

```
Num  LineID  ColA  ColB ColC
1 1 7 3.5 89.9
1 2 6.8 3.1 90.02
1 3 7.5 2.9 90
2 1 7.2 3.2 92
2 2 7.1 3.1 89.8
2 3 6.9 2.87 88
3 1 7.3 2.9 90
3 2 7.03 3.04 90
3 3 7.2 3 89.6
```

Which I would like to separate into three separate arrays or text files based on LineID value.

First array for LineID = 1

```
Num  LineID  ColA  ColB ColC
1 1 7 3.5 89.9
2 1 7.2 3.2 92
3 1 7.3 2.9 90
```

Second array for LineID=2

```
Num  LineID  ColA  ColB ColC
1 2 6.8 3.1 90.02
2 2 7.1 3.1 89.8
3 2 7.03 3.0 4 90
```

Third array for LineID=3

```
Num  LineID  ColA  ColB ColC
1 3 7.5 2.9 90
2 3 6.9 2.87 88
3 3 7.2 3 89.6
```

Has anyone got any pointers for how to do this in python or with Numpy/Pandas?

Ivan offered a good solution, I haven't checked them all yet, it just adds an extra number to the start of each line which corresponds to that line's original position in the original array/text file. I have tried it with both ',' and ' ' separated csv and space separated txt files and it comes out the same way.

```
   Num  LineID  ColA  ColB  CoLC
0    1       1   7.0   3.5  89.9
3    2       1   7.2   3.2  92.0
6    3       1   7.3   2.9  90.0
   Num  LineID  ColA  ColB   CoLC
1    1       2  6.80  3.10  90.02
4    2       2  7.10  3.10  89.80
7    3       2  7.03  3.04  90.00
   Num  LineID  ColA  ColB  CoLC
2    1       3   7.5  2.90  90.0
5    2       3   6.9  2.87  88.0
8    3       3   7.2  3.00  89.6
```

Comment: Some separators have double space between them. Try setting the division between headers to a single space: ' '

Comment: Check my solution.  The extra number is the index.  If you want to avoid that in the output to csv, you need to set the flag `index=False` when calling `to_csv`

Comment: Not only that, pandas will use its own index. you can avoid reading them with `print (id1.to_string(index=False))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help, id1, id2 and id3 have what you need, you can write a file later with each of them.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('textfile.txt', sep=" ")
id1 = data[data['LineID'] == 1]
id2 = data[data['LineID'] == 2]
id3 = data[data['LineID'] == 3]

print(id1)
print(id2)
print(id3)
```

Comment: I try this and it works except at the start of each line there is an extra number:        Num  LineID  ColA  ColB  CoLC
0    1       1   7.0   3.5  89.9
3    2       1   7.2   3.2  92.0
6    3       1   7.3   2.9  90.0
   Num  LineID  ColA  ColB   CoLC
1    1       2  6.80  3.10  90.02
4    2       2  7.10  3.10  89.80
7    3       2  7.03  3.04  90.00

Comment: I will add a note to the question as it is not obvious from the comment what I mean.

Comment: Check your header! separate them with single spaces: Num LineID ColA ColB ColC

Answer (score 2):

According that your text file would be named `example.txt`, with the following content:

```
Num  LineID  ColA  ColB ColC
1 1 7 3.5 89.9
1 2 6.8 3.1 90.02
1 3 7.5 2.9 90
2 1 7.2 3.2 92
2 2 7.1 3.1 89.8
2 3 6.9 2.87 88
3 1 7.3 2.9 90
3 2 7.03 3.04 90
3 3 7.2 3 89.6
```

You could use pandas to import it as a DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('example.txt', sep=' ')
```

Then you could filter on the line id:

```
df1 = df[df.LineID == 1]
...
```

Answer (score 1):

#### `groupby` and `to_csv`

- Be sure to include the option **`index=False`** to indicate that you don't want to include the index in the output.
- Please don't manually search for each unique `'LineID'` and subset your `DataFrame` by what's equal to that.  Use `groupby`!
- Also, you can very elegantly iterate through a `groupby` object like a dictionary. This is what I do below.

---

```
for lid, grp in df.groupby('LineID'):
    grp.to_csv(f'text_{lid}.csv', index=False, sep=' ')
```

---

#### Verify

```
from pathlib import Path

for fp in Path('.').glob('text_*.csv'):
    print(fp)
    print('-' * 80)
    print(open(fp).read())
    print()

text_1.csv
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Num LineID ColA ColB ColC
1 1 7.0 3.5 89.9
2 1 7.2 3.2 92.0
3 1 7.3 2.9 90.0


text_2.csv
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Num LineID ColA ColB ColC
1 2 6.8 3.1 90.02
2 2 7.1 3.1 89.8
3 2 7.03 3.04 90.0


text_3.csv
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Num LineID ColA ColB ColC
1 3 7.5 2.9 90.0
2 3 6.9 2.87 88.0
3 3 7.2 3.0 89.6
```

---

#### `dict` of `DataFrame` by `'LineID'`

```
dict_of_df_by_lid = dict((*df.groupby('LineID'),))
# Less Obtuse
# dict_of_df_by_lid = {k: v for k, v in df.groupby('LineID')}
```

---

#### Verify

```
for k, v in dict_of_df_by_lid.items():
    print(f'LineID: {k}')
    print('-' * 80)
    print(v)
    print()

LineID: 1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Num  LineID  ColA  ColB  ColC
0    1       1   7.0   3.5  89.9
3    2       1   7.2   3.2  92.0
6    3       1   7.3   2.9  90.0

LineID: 2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Num  LineID  ColA  ColB   ColC
1    1       2  6.80  3.10  90.02
4    2       2  7.10  3.10  89.80
7    3       2  7.03  3.04  90.00

LineID: 3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Num  LineID  ColA  ColB  ColC
2    1       3   7.5  2.90  90.0
5    2       3   6.9  2.87  88.0
8    3       3   7.2  3.00  89.6
```

Comment: hi piRSuared, is there any way to lose the first number of the output lines, they correspond to the original line positions.

Comment: @Windy71 that is the index value.  You can't get rid of it in the context of a `DataFrame`.  You **CAN** get rid of it when outputting to a file.  Set the flag `index=False` when calling `to_csv`.  This is what I've done in the example I provided.  Check the output files themselves to verify.

Answer (score 0):

If the initial file is large, or if you want to save memory, and you can have more open files than FileID, you can even process it one line at a time with the csv module.

Assuming the initial file is `file.txt` and that you want to split it into several `file_i.txt` files where `i` is the LineID:

```
import csv

ident = 'LineID'
with open('file.txt') as fdin:
    files = {}                # to store the output files and writers
    rd = csv.DictReader(fdin, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in rd:
        if not row[ident] in files:    # found a new LineID
            fout = open('file_{}.txt'.format(row[ident]), 'w', newline='') # create the file
            wr = csv.DictWriter(fout, rd.fieldnames)                       # and the associated writer
            wr.writeheader()                                               # write the header
            files[row[ident]] = (wr, fout)                                 # store everything in files
        files[row[ident]][0].writerow(row)              # write each row to the appropriate file

# close the output files
for id in files:
    files[id][1].close()
```